# Trying to remove padding between label and combobox

Tags: html, css, combobox

This seems like it would be simple but for the life of me I can't seem to crack this. I have two divs side by side, each of which contains a component, one a text field, and one a combo box. Each has a label positioned over it, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I'd like for the combobox to be the same height as the text field, but it seems as though any height I add to it gets added at the bottom, not the top. So the combobox itself is always bumped a little bit down, causing it to not line up with the text field. I've tried every css trick I could think of to reduce the padding between the label 'Dynamically Deployed' and the combobox beneath it, but I can't get it to match the behavior of the 'Name' label and text input beneath it. Even if this will never work, that would be good to know so I can move on. I also have nothing against getting rid of the  tags altogether and replacing it with a different type of selection element if a good one exists out there. Does anyone have any ideas?

The HTML for the page looks like this:

```
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="form-group-sm">
        <label class="rf-form-label-top" for="environment_version"><font
        size="2"><b>Name</b></font></label> <input type="text" type="submit"
        class="form-control-sm" id="testengine_name" name="testengine_name"
        ng-model="TestEngineResourceFileParams.name"
        style='width: 300px; height: 25px' />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="form-group-sm">
        <label class="rf-combo-label" for="dynamicdeployed"> <font
        size="2"><b>Dynamically Deployed</b></font></label>
        <div style="clear: both; height: 0px"></div>
        <select class="rf-engine-combo-group-form" name="dynamicallydeployed"
        id="dynamicallydeployed"
        ng-model="TestEngineResourceFileParams.dynamic_deploypment">
            <option selected value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.rf-form-label-top {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.rf-engine-combo-group-form {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline:0px;
}

.rf-combo-label {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.rf-form-control-sm {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow
        ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out
        .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We'll need your code for the whole area you screenshot, HTML and CSS, to reproduce this and thus help you.

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Will do, let me pare it down to its simplest form and I'll post it.

Comment: Ok I added a test page that only contains the relevant elements (and I removed the help tips to get them out of the equation as well). That HTML and CSS should reproduce what I'm seeing.

Comment: [Is this the result you're after?](https://jsfiddle.net/mqfqp1sy/4/) I will add this as an answer if yes, but given I had to edit/remove some of your code, I'd rather make sure. You have the "wrong" classes (according to my perspective) and even some inline CSS which will overwrite the CSS rules you have, causing different rendering of the two elements.

Comment: @chriskirknielsenThat's perfect, thanks! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.  As for the classes what do you mean by 'wrong'?  Also, the inline CSS was just me messing around trying to tweak things, all that will be removed.

Comment: I have posted an answer with working code. The classes you were using didn't make 100% sense to me (as they effectively made the two elements different), so I have made changes to that effect in your markup. I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly reworked markup/styling to achieve the result you're after - see my comments below and in the code:

```css
/* Below are 3 additions to your styles */
* { box-sizing: border-box; } /* Ensure the size of elements is correct */
.wrapper { display: flex; } /* Place your two blocks next to each other with flexbox */
label { display: block; } /* Opinionated; This is dispensable */ 

/* Original styles below; changed are commented */
.rf-form-label-top { /* Unused in the markup, removed for clarity */ }

.rf-engine-combo-group-form { /* Unused in the markup, removed for clarity */ }

.rf-combo-label {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold; /* Better than using HTML <b> */
}
.rf-form-control-sm {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow
        ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out
        .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- Added around your markup to set your elements in a flex context -->
 <div class="main-block">
   <div class="rf-form-group-sm">
     <label class="rf-combo-label" for="testengine_name">Name</label>
     <input type="text"
     class="rf-form-control-sm" id="testengine_name" name="testengine_name"
     ng-model="TestEngineResourceFileParams.name" />
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main-block">
   <div class="rf-form-group-sm">
     <label class="rf-combo-label" for="dynamicallydeployed">Dynamically Deployed</label>
     <select class="rf-form-control-sm" name="dynamicallydeployed"
     id="dynamicallydeployed"
     ng-model="TestEngineResourceFileParams.dynamic_deploypment">
       <option selected value="true">true</option>
       <option value="false">false</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have taken the liberty to improve the markup by removing the deprecated `<font>` and `<b>` tags, styling the `<label>`s in the CSS directly. A few classes didn't make sense so I have replaced them with the "proper" ones (in my opinion) in the markup, and removed the classes in the styles (see comments in the CSS). Also, a few things weren't good: your text `<input>` had both `type="text"` and `type="submit"`. Additionally, the labels' `for` attribute were pointing to inexistent `id`s - this has also been fixed.

This code provides the result but as this is your project, I cannot ensure it fits perfectly, so you might need to make adjustments.

Comment: This did it, thanks - and I really appreciate the notes/markups as I'm fairly new to all this. I've already ported the code into the project and it works like a charm!